# Import cannot be resolved pylance error in vscode, have tried a few fixes

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, import, pylint

I am having trouble using pylint for my Django app. I am receiving a couple of errors and have resolved some using other threads but the main one I am still running into is *Import ".forms" could not be resolved*.

I am hitting this error inside the *views.py* file when trying to import from *forms.py* with the following import `from .forms import ArtistForm` (ArtistForm being a class).

I have tried following the below resources but have not been very successful.

- https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#unresolved-import-warnings

This is what I added to my .vscode/settings.json to try and resolve with the above -

`"python.analysis.extraPaths": ["tunr/", "./tunr/templates/tunr"]`

I also tried using the .env fix detailed in the below article -

- https://appdividend.com/2021/03/26/python-unresolved-import/

I am new to coding so I have been having trouble fully understanding how to fix this. Any help is appreciated.

Below is my file structure, not the *tunr* folder is at the root:

```
tunr
     ├── apps.py
     ├── models.py
     ├── templates
     │   └── tunr
     │       ├── artist_detail.html
     │       ├── artist_form.html
     │       ├── artist_list.html
     │       ├── base.html
     │       ├── forms.py
     │       ├── song_detail.html
     │       └── song_list.html
     └── views.py
```

Let me know if any other information will be helpful.

Comment: your forms is inside templates folder, please move it to tunr folder, it solve the issue

Comment: @SanthoshReddy thank you very much. What an easy fix. I appreciate the assistance, I was getting very frustrated.

Comment: i will be moving it to answer

Answer (score 1):

In VS Code go to View Command Palette. Then search Python: Select Interpreter and select it. Next choose Recommended option. After select an option wait a few seconds. Then your problem will be solved.

Comment: Which interpreter is recommended?